# REST WCF Ninject 3.2 Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, ninject

I want to use Ninject with REST WCF.
I found this [article](http://www.aaronstannard.com/dependency-injection-ninject-wcf-service)
where the implementation looks quite easy. The problem is that I can't find NinjectWcfApplication which my Global.asax needs to inherit anywhere in my project. The installed packages are - Ninject, Ninject.Extensions.Wcf and Ninject.Web.Common.

Also maybe there is a better way of REST WCF Ninject implementation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you are using Ninject 3.2 and it doesn't containg this class. Author of article is using Ninject 2.2. Maybe this [Upgrading Ninject/Ninject WCF Extensions to the latest version 3.0.0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390809/upgrading-ninject-ninject-wcf-extensions-to-the-latest-version-3-0-0-5) will be usefull for you.

Comment: I've read this article, but I have Ninject.Web.Common already  installed and App_Start is empty.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood something but author of article override CreateKernel method of NinjectWcfApplication now you can override the same method in the NinjectHttpApplication. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, I misunderstood :) Thanks a lot!